# get the mail file size, type, name in c#

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

How to get the email attachment file size, name, type programmatically with visual studio 2010 and

c#.net and when the  button clicked in th 
it send mail with above details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the MailItem.Attachments collection and use Attachment.FileName and Attachment.Size properties.

Comment: thx, Now i want to get the file type (eg. image, text, word, excel), then how do i get, because right now only Olbyvalue comes, instead of image, text etc.

Comment: Use the Attchment.FileName property and extract the file extension.

Comment: i got the file name, but i need the type of file, like image / text file, so that i need to check its extension and then decide, is there any alternate way to get the type of file?

Comment: If you have a file name, all you need to do is extract the extension - find the last position of ".". Everything after that is the extension.